# CMake FindXercesC.cmake does not find my XercesC

Tags: c++, cmake, xerces

On my system (Fedora 26), I installed XercesC using yum (aka dnf).  The XercesC header files are located in

> /usr/include/xercesc-2.7.0/xercesc

and the library is

> /usr/lib64/libxerces-c.so.27.

I have tried the official `FindXercesC.cmake` as well as a number of posted versions of this package finder.  I also attempted many edits to the posted `*.cmake` files.  None of them can locate XercesC and I have to resort to manually entering the locations for the headers and library.

Is there a CMake package finder for XercesC that will automatically locate XercesC on my system?

Comment: Kind of hard to figure out what's going on if you don't post the cmake code.

Comment: Directory `/usr/include/xercesc-2.7.0` definitely is not a default include path. Not sure why Fedora chooses to install the package there. Hint CMake about it by setting [CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH.html) variable (either from command line or inside your script). Also, you should have a library *without* so-version for being detectable by CMake. Add **precise error message** to the question post.

Comment: Thank you.  The library without so-version is in /usr/lib64/xercesc-2.7.0.  Setting the CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH and CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH variables to the appropriate directories fixed the problem.

Comment: @Tsyvarev could You please post Your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Kamiccolo: Done. Thank for reminding :)

Answer (score 5):

Normally, CMake search things only in *default* directories. E.g., `/usr/include` directory is automatically searched for the header files.

But directory `/usr/include/xercesc-2.7.0` isn't a default for CMake (it is not default for compiler too), so CMake cannot find things there without an explicit hint. For hint CMake about include directory to search, set *CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH* variable. E.g., via command line:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/xercesc-2.7.0 <other_params>
```

Similar is true for searching library files: CMake automatically searches libraries under `/usr/lib64/`, but not under `/usr/lib64/xercesc-2.7.0`. Also, CMake can find only library without *so-version*, so it cannot find file `/usr/lib64/libxerces-c.so.27`. For finding a file `/usr/lib64/xercesc-2.7.0/libxerces-c.so` you need to hint CMake with *CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH* variable.

---

According to the [xercesc sources](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/xerces/c/trunk/), it supports searching the package via `pkg-config` and via *CONFIG* mode of `find_package`. Probably, these variants won't require additional hints.

Searching via `pkg-config` can be performed with [pkg_check_modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/FindPkgConfig.html#command:pkg_check_modules), for use `find_package` in *CONFIG* mode either add this option to the call `find_package(XercesC)`, or simply remove `FindXercesC.cmake` script.